# Extraer reseñas de sitios web de Free Tours

Tags: base-de-datos, r

Mi intención es extraer las reseñas de los free tours que aparecen en estas páginas:
Guruwalks ( https://www.guruwalk.com/es/walks/39405-free-tour-malaga-con-guias-profesionales )
Freetour.com ( https://www.freetour.com/es/budapest/free-tour-budapest-imperial )

Estoy trabajando con R en Windows, pero al usar RSelenium me da error.

Mi código inicial es:

```
#Loading the rvest package
library(rvest)
library(magrittr) # for the '%>%' pipe symbols
library(RSelenium) # to get the loaded html of 
library(purrr) # for 'map_chr' to get reply 

df_0<-data.frame(tour=character(),
                 dates=character(),
                 names=character(),
                 starts=character(),
                 reviews=character())

url_google <- list("https://www.guruwalk.com/es/walks/39405-free-tour-malaga-con-guias-profesionales")

for (apps in url_google) { 

  #Specifying the url for desired website to be scrapped
  url <- apps

  # starting local RSelenium (this is the only way to start RSelenium that is working for me atm)
  selCommand <- wdman::selenium(jvmargs = c("-Dwebdriver.chrome.verboseLogging=true"), retcommand = TRUE)
  shell(selCommand, wait = FALSE, minimized = TRUE)
  remDr <- remoteDriver(port = 4567L, browserName = "firefox") 
  remDr$open()
  
  require(RSelenium)

  # go to website
  remDr$navigate(URL)
```

El error es:

```
Show in New Window
Error: Summary: SessionNotCreatedException
Detail: A new session could not be created.
Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

¿Cómo puedo resolverlo? Gracias

Comment: Hola, David. ¿Estás copiando el código tal cual de algún ejemplo que viste en otro lado o lo adaptaste a tu caso particular? Lo pregunto porque por ejemplo, tu variable url_google tiene un sólo elemento y, por tanto, no te va a dar ningún resultado en tu iteración. Sugiero revises bien y pongas código que se adapte más o menos a lo que necesitas para que alguien te pueda dar una mejor retroalimentación.

Comment: Buenas Alejandro, si lo he ido creando yo con ejemplos de otros lado. Si se que url_google tiene solo un elemento ahora mismo, ya que uso solo un elemento para probar si funciona, ya meteré más elementos para que haya una interacción. El problema es que no me funciona RSelinium, cuando en otras ocasiones si me sirvió.